# Where should I ask question on control system engineering?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Control system engineering covers topics such as *LTI systems* and *PID and other controllers*.

There are several possible sites I might try and I can't make a good decision:

- [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
- [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Can anyone advise me on how to chose between those four? I am asking about *theoretical* questions regarding control systems, that means questions that are **NOT** about using Matlab to simulate them or wiring them.

Comment: PID was something covered in the EE part of my curriculum so possibly [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pid-controller)?  Not sure about the theoretical aspect though (I'm not part of the EE.SE community).

Comment: PID and other control systems are quite not only used in electronics. For example I need one to calculate guided rocket control in my computer game - no electronics, but no programming either, I just have the LTI system and I§m trying to linearize it.

Comment: Yeah.  I've never browsed Engineering but I'd vote for that one of the 4 communities you lists.

Comment: [Robotics.se] perhaps? Though perhaps not if there's nothing physical involved.